# How to find the determinant of this 3*3 matrix?

Tags: matrices

Hello I can't find the answer of this question. Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

If the determinant of this matrix is 7$
$
    \begin{matrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{matrix}
$.
What will be the determinant of this matrix:

$
\begin{matrix}
a & 2a+b & 5c \\
d & 2d+e & 5f \\
g & 2g+h & 5i \\
\end{matrix}
$

Comment: Do you know how column operations (and row operations) affect the determinant?

Comment: adding a multiple of one column to another column does not change the value of the determinant

Comment: Thank you @Arthur.

Comment: Thank you  @J.W.Tanner Tanner

Answer (score 1):

You may factor out $5$ from the determinant and subtract twice the first column from the second.

Therefore the answer is $5(7)=35$

Comment: Thank you again for your help @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani.

Comment: @aita.kane Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Comment: do you know a great book to master linear algebra, please?

Comment: @aita.kane  Try David Pool, Linear Algebra, A Modern Introduction. 4th edition.

Comment: Thank you. That's noted